# Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError' exception kotlin while sorting Custom Data Object

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using `sortBy`,`sortWith`,`sortedBy`,`sortedWith` inline functions for sorting a `List` or `ArrayList` of custom objects but its throwing exception:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError' exception
```

My Custom class is:

```
@Parcelize
data class Payload(
        var addressLine1: String,
        var addressLine2: String,
        var city: String,
        val country: String,
        var default: Boolean,
        val id: String
) : Parcelable
```

addresslist is of type List,it could be either List or ArrayList I have tried with both DS

```
val list=(addressList as MutableList).sortBy { it.default }
```

I don't know why this sorting is not working. Please any help with it.

Comment: Hi @Kanchan. Welcome here. What do you want to sort? A list of `Payload`?

Comment: correct ,its throwing inaccessible error

Answer (score 1):

You can have your address list sorted by its `default` value just like this:

```
val sortedList = addressList.sortedBy { it.default }
```

Or in reverse order:

```
val sortedList = addressList.sortedByDescending { it.default }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your addressList is a constant variable. Change it to a **var**. then you will be able to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
val sortedList = addressList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.pos})
```

pos can be replaced with any attribute with which you want to sort the list.